# Residual vs. fits

Tags: least-squares, endogeneity

Based on the plot, would it be OK to assume the errors have mean zero (aprox. half of them are under and the other half above zero line) given the strict exogeneity assumption by OLS?

[image: Residual vs. Fits]

[image: Residuals vs. Fits (Ln transformation)]

Comment: This graph is a residual plot. Residuals average to zero by the design of linear regression, I don't think you need to assume your model did that (or using residual plot is a wrong tool). More importantly, the the normality and homoskedasticity of the residual should be examined.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight I am not a statistician. However, it was argued that my model suffers from endogeneity. I was hoping that I can assume exogeneity of regressors based on the plot above.

Comment: I'm a statistics laymen myself, fair warning --- but ideally, the residuals of a model show no distinct pattern since it should be 'random noise' --- clearly in your residuals, it looks the variance in error for Y changes sharply as X increases. I'm not certain what conclusion you would derive from that in terms of improving your model. EDIT: Some googling suggests that even with a mean 0 at every X, non-constant variance is a problem that may be fixiable with a transformation.

Comment: @John Babson I forgot to mention that the data is time series cross sectional.

Comment: As long as you include a constant in your regression, the residuals will average to zero even if your model suffers from endogeneity...A residual plot cannot provide evidence for exogeneity. Because you have panel data your errors will not be homoskedastic. When looking at the residual plot its concerning that the mean of the error term seems to shift with the fitted value.  The plot should look random but instead it has that dimond shape.  This could mean your regression equation is not properly specified.

Comment: @Zachary Blumenfeld I have added second plot. The dependent variable was transformed with Ln. I think it looks slightly better, how would you interpret the second plot?

Comment: @ZacharyBlumenfeld, why not make that an official answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logged transform model looks better on the residual plot but its not perfect.  That football like shape is a sign of heteroskedasticity. I cannot tell you whether or not the log transformation is the solution to your problems based solely on a residual plot.  This will depend on the theoretical underpinnings of the process your trying to model, what your intentions are (forecasting versus economic explination) how easy it is to interpret and how complicated your willing to make your model.  You should decide if this log transformation makes sense for yourself.

As I said in an above comment, because your using panel data and have a fixed time effect model (time dummies) your residuals will be serially correlated and most likely heteroskedastic.  You can still estimate the linear regression in the same fashion but you must adjust your standard errors via clustering.

As far as endogeniety is concerned, you cannot infer anything from a residual plot.  To see why this is define the population model as

$$
y_{t,p} = \beta_0 + \beta_1\mathbf{x}_{t,p} + \delta_t + \gamma_p + \varepsilon_{t,p}
$$
and the estimated model as 
$$
y_{t,p} = \hat\beta_0 + \hat\beta_1\mathbf{x}_{t,p} + \hat\delta_t + \hat\gamma_p + \hat\varepsilon_{t,p}
$$
In the above, $t$ and $p$ are time and product indexes respectively, $\mathbf{x}$ are the product attributes, $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ are the true constant term and attribute parameters respectively, and $\delta$ and $\gamma$ are the true time and product fixed effect parameters.  The values in the estimated model are "hatted" since they are estimates of the true parameter values.  Recall that we cannot see the true parameter values directly, but only obtain the "hatted" estimates via regression analysis.

Endogeneity happens when at least one of your left hand variables $\mathbf{x}$ is correlated with the error term $\varepsilon$.
 We can write this in many different ways.

$$E[\varepsilon_{t,p}\,|\,\mathbf{x}_{t,p}] \neq \mathbf{0} $$ $$\mathrm{cov}( \varepsilon_{t,p},\mathbf{x}_{t,p}) \neq \mathbf{0} $$ $$E[\mathbf{x}_{t,p}\varepsilon_{t,p}] \neq \mathbf{0}$$
All of these pretty much say the same thing but it's important to realize that $\varepsilon$ is the error term for the true population model, and *not* the residual term for the estimated model $\hat\varepsilon$, which is what your plotting.  By construction of the linear regression model, when a constant is included
$$\sum_{t=1}^T\sum_{p=1}^P\hat\varepsilon_{t,p} = 0$$ $$\sum_{t=1}^T\sum_{p=1}^P(\mathbf{x}_{t,p}\hat\varepsilon_{t,p})= 0$$

Essential the linear model assumes no endogeneity when estimating the parameters, so if you do in fact have endogeneity issues in the true population model, the parameter estimates you obtain (the "hatted values") will, in almost all cases, be biased estimates of the true parameters.

This is what makes endogeniety such a challenging problem to deal with in research, you cannot see it directly by examining the model estimates and residual plots.  It requires much more clever thinking, such as structural specifications and instrumental variables to identify and treat endogeneity issues emperically.

It's also not a bad idea to look at a histogram of your residuals.   The residuals should appear normal, the level of formal normality testing employed is a matter of taste.  for these types of models I am more concerned about the symmetry of the distribution and that the tails are not incredibly thick (as in a Cauchy).  If the histogram is not symmetrical than the regression model is not giving you useful information as it is currently specified.

Comment: Just to highlight: **endogeneity cannot be proved/disproved empirically**. It's a structural argument, which is uncomfortable for many people to deal with.

Comment: I partially agree with what you are saying.  But in the instrumental variables camp of econometricians you can use a Housman-Wu specification test to prove an OLS estimator is inconsistent when compared to a consistant IV or 2SLS estimator.  Since the IV estimator is predicated on adjusting for endogeneity, it is reasonable to interpret the rejection of the null as empirical proof for endogeneity.  Of course we must assume that the IV model is exogenous, which to your point comes from a structural argument.

Comment: @Zachary Blumenfeld Thanks for your answer. Regarding endogeneity, how then can I rebute my advisor claims about endogeneity and justify mine position that linear OLS model I have used produced adequate results? Would it be the Housman-Wu test? Or is somethig else? In addition, I presume that I cannot just "say" that all variables were considered exogenous? Thank you again for understanding as I am not a statistician but willing to learn, and currently I am faced with issues I cannot solve all by myself.

Comment: I agree with your adviser, the model is endogenous.  From the supply side, the error term would contain variations in input prices for the products which would be correlated with the products attributes.  On the demand side, the error term also contains changes in consumer income which would effect price, a negative change in income would lower quantity demanded in turn lowering the price.  Suppliers, seeking to maximize profit, may decrease product quality as a result. So there error term and attributes would be correlated here as well.

Comment: Most good models for market prices in econometrics are structured via supply and demand equations. You model is missing some important parts. http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~wgreene/Text/Edition7/M08_GREE5381_07_SE_C08-checked.pdf is a good starting point to making a more complete model, look at example 8.4 first as this may apply to what your doing (although they have more variables than you). The rest of the chapter covers all sorts of endogeneity issues and solutions. You should also get comfortable with matrix algebra.

Comment: @ZacharyBlumenfeld, you're right, but I'm going to restate what you said more carefully to help OP: The Hausman-Wu statistic tests if a 2SLS with instrumental variables is *different* from an OLS model, and nothing more. Now, if the OLS is endogenous and the IV used in 2SLS is exogenous, then the Hausman test will show that the OLS model was inconsistent. A negative Hausman test may mean two things: the OLS model was exogenous **or** the IV isn't useful. Also, a positive test may mean the IV is exogenous, but it doesn't show there aren't other endogenous variables. That's an argument.

Answer (score 0):

A little more information or example data may be helpful. If this is a time series, that means each X value is the residual error at a different point in time. That means as your fitted model chugged along the time series, while overall the model didn't systematically overestimate or underestimate the true values (the deviations average around zero) .... the error didn't seem to vary randomly. It means the model was pretty accurate at the beginning of the time frame ---- became much less accurate in the middle (up and down) .... then became somewhat more accurate yet again. I don't know --- doesn't seem normal for a predictive model. Might be a data cleansing issue --- or the noise variance/ inherent unpredictability of whatever you were modeling changed at one point (which doesn't happen too often in nature). More info is needed, I think.

Comment: I was modeling product price based on its attributes in order to observe products' price change between years within analysed period, i.e. for which data is collected. I was using time dummy variable to capture price change.

Comment: This is definitely beyond my paygrade so you may have to wait for a time series expert, but I did find this remark on "heteroscedasticity of residuals in time series": In time series data, [residual] heteroscedasticity is more often the result of interactions between model predictors and omitted variables, and so is another sign of a fundamental misspecification. OLS estimates in the presence of heteroscedasticity exhibit virtually identical problems to those associated with autocorrelation; they are unbiased, but no longer have minimum variance among unbiased estimators,

Comment: and standard formulas for estimator variance become biased. Unless heteroscedasticity is pronounced, distortion of the standard errors is small, and significance tests are largely unaffected. With most economic data, the effects of heteroscedasticity will be minor compared to the effects of autocorrelation.